# How a const reference bind to an object of a different type

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, reference

The type of a reference and the object to which the reference refers must match exactly. It's mean is that,

```
double dval = 3.14; 
int &refi = dval;
```

will be given a compiler error.

But when a const reference binds to different type object is allowed. How is it possible (I'm asking an explenation from c++ standards view)and why?

Regards,
Tunahan.

Comment: FYI, conversion produces a temporary.

Comment: @LogicStuff, thanks a lot.